# How to center an Icon in an ElevatedButton?

Tags: flutter, button, alignment

How to center my Icon in ElevatedButton widget ?

Here is my code :

```
ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    shape: CircleBorder(),
    primary: itemColor.color),
  child: Center(child: Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.white))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope its helpful to you.

```
     ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              shape: CircleBorder(),
            ),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.check,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Comment: It does not work as well. I have a padding on the left.

Comment: can you add your output screenshot